# sed: -e expression #1, char 52: Invalid range end

Tags: regex, sed, character-class

I have this regex expression that validates on regex101:
`[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.+[a-zA-Z0-9-]{2,4}`

But when I try to run it with sed I get: `sed: -e expression #1, char 52: Invalid range end`

As far as I understand this is normally a problem when you define your range like:
A-z in some versions of sed, but here I'm putting a-zA-Z? So I guess it's the special chars causing the error, but how do I solve it?

Sed:
`$( sed -E -n '/[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.+[a-zA-Z0-9-]{2,4}/p' < emails.txt )`

Comment: If i remove the special chars from the character classes it works, but then I don't get the selection needed from the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first character class `[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]` this is no valid range: `9-_`

Move `-` to last character in your character class: `[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]`